# allround automations pl/sql developer on windows 7 - TNS over IP connect to remote db

Tags: oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I am really having very hard time making PL/SQL developer [PL/SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) work on my windows 7 64-bit OS. I have Oracle 10g standard edition installed already. I tried with PL/SQL developer version 7 and 8 with no luck. Do anyone tried doing it?. **Main objective is to just establish a TCP over IP connection to a remote Oracle 10g database from PL/SQL developer**. The PL/SQL developer website states it supports windows 7 though but it's making me crazy.

Comment: hard to help if you don't say how exactly it is not working...

Comment: @Jeffrey I got this resolved. I just ran it as administrator and got it resolved. This link helped here http://www.allroundautomations.com/threads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=cfrm&PHPSESSID=c3aee8954fd6f46d572831670c097ff5

Comment: That's great A_Var. stackoverflow is a wiki, so it'd be a great idea if you post (a) what was not working, and (b) your answer and accept it (yes, you can accept your own answer). That way you'll help others who come later with the same problem. Cheers!

Comment: @Jeffrey Can you go through my answer and see if it makes sense. Thankx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got PL/SQL Developer working on my Windows 7 OS. Here goes the step by step instructions on how I did it.

- First installed Oracle 10g 32-bit client runtime environment which is sufficient enough for opening a TCP over IP connection to a remote Oracle 10g database from PL/SQL Developer. It is also possible to connect using Oracle InstantClient (which is more light only 300 Kb) [InstantClient_PL/SQL](http://jasonvogel.blogspot.com/2007/10/oracle-instantclient-tnsping-and-plsql.html).
- Than installed PL/SQL Developer version 8.0.4 (latest as of now) and copied over tnsnames.ora file into C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN.
- Now I can open a vpn connection for a remote database and connect directly to the remote db from PL/SQL developer using a TNS over IP connection.
- The only caveat here is to open PL/SQL Developer as an administrator. This is where I went wrong and PL/SQL developer crapped out with a blank window.